# How to measure the peak region of an AC voltage using an ADC

Tags: ac, adc

I am wanting to measure JUST the peak voltage region of an AC waveform i.e. like the top 20 volts of a 130 volt 100kHz waveform.

I want to limit the measurement to just the peak region so that I can better see small changes in the amplitude of the waveform when measured with an ADC.

Note that the amplitude of the waveform changes very slowly over time and I am NOT interested in the absolute value, rather the comparative value to the last measurement.

Does anyone have any suggestions of how I might be able to achieve this.

Comment: You could use a peak detector circuit and connect it's output to the ADC

Comment: Will that not just sample the peak of the whole waveform and as such I will lose resolution? i.e. I'll be converting 0-130V to 0-5V (for instance), rather than 110-130V to 0-5V ... if that makes sense.

Comment: You can compare the instantaneous voltage to "the previous peak" minus 20 V, or to a value computed from a-priori knowledge: if the 130 V was RMS, "rectangular" would result in about 110 V, "triangular" would result in 205 V. 100 kHz *only* would mean *sine* with 184 V peak - *every* peak, as changes in amplitude or wave form would add non-100 kHz components.

Comment: @Vernon, I thought you just wanted to feed the amplitude info to the ADC. A 0-130V sine wave will get converted to a DC 130V by the peak detector. If the peak changes to 131V, output will change to 131V and so on. If this is not what you wanted, may be you can draw a picture of the ideal waveform that you want to feed to the ADC.

Comment: What measurement resolution do you need? This information is vital.

Comment: @sai the issue is the resolution. In simple terms, feeding a 130V DC into the ADC will give me a resolution of around 30mV, whereas if I feed in just the top 20V then the resolution is around 5mV. Now I don't know exactly what resolution I will need, but I want to try and maximise it, hence my question.

Comment: @Andyaka see my comment above. Until I start testing a solution I don't really know what I need ... so I'm just trying to start with the best resolution possible. The bulk of the 130V is not important to me, it's just the very top that I'm interested in.

Comment: @Vernon, from what I understand, if your AC signal is Vin, you basically want to subtract an offset of say ~110V and feed the result to the ADC. Would a normal voltage subtractor like the one given here work? https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/opamp/op-amp-building-blocks.html#:~:text=The%20Voltage%20Subtractor,to%20be%20subtracted%20from%20another.

Comment: @sai, yes that is exactly what I want to do. A voltage subtractor might work ... I think I'll have to drop the 130V into the 5V range, subtract a reference voltage and then amplify the result. I'll do some testing. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If it is possible to load the Vin with a few uA then, you could try some thing like the below. This will give you a good resolution.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @sai, I'll have a play around with it.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to limit the measurement to just the peak region so that I can better see small changes in the amplitude of the waveform when measured with an ADC.

This doesn't follow. Just run the ADC all the time and digitally detect peaks and reduce the data on the fly. It's much, much easier than doing it in the analog realm accurately.

But since you want amplitude, and not merely peaks, you could use a better algorithm. The wave, per your description, is a bandwidth-limited AM modulated sine wave. It must be AM modulated, since without modulation it has bandwidth 0 and its amplitude must be constant. Any changes in amplitude imply non-zero bandwidth around the carrier frequency. You can AM-demodulate with a matching bandwidth, and you'll recover the amplitude as a continuous signal - with values between the peaks too :)

Comment: I'm not trying to detect a modulated signal, I'm trying to dynamically tune an LC circuit. It's driven by a know frequency and the resulting waveform is at it's peak voltage when the LC circuit is precisely tuned to the driver frequency. I want to detect that peak voltage with the greatest resolution possible.

Comment: @Vernon - Do you care what the peak voltage is, or do you just want to detect the peak as you tune your circuit?

Comment: @SteveSh no I don't need to know what the actual peak voltage is. I just need a value that I can compare to previous readings to see how if it is greater than, less than or equal to.